# How to get event when power button android is pressed

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Need help, I'm making a screen locker app using React Native, and want to get an event when the android power button is pressed...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the react-native-keyevent package for react native.

```
componentDidMount() {
KeyEvent.onKeyDownListener((keyEvent) => {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode === 'Keycode of the power button'){
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            //Your SOS Function here
        }, 1000)
    }
});

KeyEvent.onKeyUpListener((keyEvent) => {
    if (keyEvent.keyCode === 'Keycode of the power button'){
        clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    }
    })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  KeyEvent.removeKeyDownListener();
  KeyEvent.removeKeyUpListener();
}
```

Comment: any link github repo or article about how to use that sir ?

Comment: Yes, you can download repo https://github.com/kevinejohn/react-native-keyevent/blob/master/index.js

Comment: thats repo stil working sir ? i don't know for sure how to Implement " onConfigurationChanged method in MainActivity.java " because it still show error